# Why did the timer for this Breath of the Wild speedrun start late?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I don't know if this speedrun of LoZ: BotW is official or not, but I was curious as to why the timer started after Link picked up the first chilli pepper?

Comment: @Lemon "Use this tag for questions about speedrunning in general - if your question is game-specific, please use the game's tag **instead**.". The speedrun tag should not be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the timer starts late is because of the DLC, you're allowed to shave off 45 seconds from the beginning.

Rules below are for the "All main quests" completion, from [Speedrun.com](https://www.speedrun.com/botw#All_Main_Quests):

> DLC Rules:
>   Original DLC disallows the usage of Champions Ballad DLC items/bonuses.
>
> If you have DLC installed, you can use the following conditions to start your timer early, to counteract DLC cutscenes:
>
> 1. –45 seconds for the Master Trials cutscene.
>      Condition 1: Must not be in Master Mode.
>      Condition 2: Cannot use any chests or bonuses from the Master Trials
> 2. –52 seconds for the Champions' Ballad cutscene.

Comment: Do you have a source where that quote is from?

Comment: Yep - https://www.speedrun.com/botw#All_Main_Quests, under "view rules"